# How do I append custom query strings to grails Resources using a mapper?

Tags: java, grails, resources

I would like to create a Grails resources mapper that appends a query string to the actualUrl. All attempts thus far have failed - but maybe I'm going about things the wrong way. Example code follows;

```
import org.grails.plugin.resource.mapper.MapperPhase
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory

class GlobalizationResourceMapper {

    def log = LogFactory.getLog(this.class)
    def phase = MapperPhase.RENAMING
    def operation = "globalizationquerystring"
    def priority = -1

    static defaultExcludes = ['**/*.png', '**/*.gif', '**/*.jpg', '**/*.jpeg', '**/*.gz', '**/*.zip']
    static defaultIncludes = ['**/*.js','**/*.gsp']

    /**
     * Cache the resource based on current language in use. Do this by appending a query string on the resource URL indicating language.
     */
    def map(resource, config) {
        def query = [l:'en_US']
        resource.actualUrl = resource.actualUrl + '?' + query.collect { it }.join('&')
        if (log.debugEnabled) log.debug "Modified URL: ${resource.actualUrl}"
        log.info "Modified URL: ${resource.actualUrl}"
    }
}
```

The actual URL gets changed appropriately, but any resource requested with it ends up in a redirect loop and 404's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append the params to the URL in `*Resources.groovy` i.e. at the point where the resource is declared (rather than in the mapper) using:

```
resource url: '/js/foo.js', wrapper: { baseUrl ->          
  def query = [l:'en_US']
  baseUrl + '?' + query.collect { it }.join('&')
}
```

Comment: What is passed to the wrapper closure as baseUrl is not only the url, '/js/foo.js' in this example. It's the whole tag string, like '<script src="/js/foo.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>'

Comment: I ended up changing my solution slightly and just included;
`<script src="${createLink(uri:'/js/myfile.js')}?lang=${lang}"></script>` instead.