# Grails URL with parameters in resource declaration

Tags: grails, resources

Grails 2.1

I've declared the following new resource module to support Google Map API in  my views:

```
'google-map' {
    resource url: 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyGoogleApiKeyGoesHere&sensor=false', attrs: [type: "js"], disposition: 'head'
}
```

Now when I include this module into some of my pages I get the following HTML code in result:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

As you can see the parameters part of URL was removed by some reason which causes an error (Google says that sensor parameter is required when I try to open the page).

Does anybody know how to prevent Grails Resources plug-in from removing query parameters from URLs?

Comment: I think that the wrapper is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815349/how-do-i-append-custom-query-strings-to-grails-resources-using-a-mapper