# How to add Google web font css to Grails resources

Tags: grails, fonts, resources, grails-resources-plugin

What is the right way to add a **Google web font css** dependency to a grails app using the resources plugin?

For some reason, the **grails resources plugin** seems to want to remove the query string.

```
modules = {
    mainLayout {
        dependsOn 'bootstrap-css,bootstrap-responsive-css,bootstrap-dropdown'
        resource url: 'css/main.css'
        resource url: 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Snowburst One', attrs: [type: "css"]
    }
}
```

The HTML has this:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815349/how-do-i-append-custom-query-strings-to-grails-resources-using-a-mapper

Answer (score 0):

Include the link to the web font a pi in your main layout file:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=.../>
```